# Zero error randomized communication complexity vs deterministic communication complexity

Tags: communication-complexity

It is known that for $\Theta(1)$ error the worst case definition of randomized communication complexity and average case definition are equivalent. But when the error is $0$, the worst case randomized communication complexity is same as deterministic communication complexity.

Is any function known to have super-constant deterministic communication complexity but constant zero error randomized communication complexity?

More generally, what is a witness function that separates deterministic communication complexity and zero-error randomized communication complexity?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean the opposite (small randomized, but large deterministic)?

Comment: Yes, extremely sorry for that mess. I want constant zero-error randomized communication complexity but super constant deterministic communication complexity.

I was looking t the problem of $k$-set disjointness. As $R_0(f)=O(max\{R^1(f), R^1(\text{not }f)\})$ and Hastad-Wigderson protocol already gives a one-sided protocol for $k$-set disjointness of cost $O(k)$ the problem boils down to proving a constant cost randomized bounded-error one-sided upper bound for not-k-set-disjointness. Is there already a result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indeed, for distjointness of sets of size $\log(n)$ out of $n$ items, it is known that 
the $0$-error randomized communication complexity is $\Theta(\log n)$, while the deterministic
complexity is $\Theta(\log^2 n)$.

Recall that there can be at most a quadratic gap since the $0$-error randomized complexity is bounded from below by the non-deterministic and co-non-deterministic complexities.

See: http://mirror.theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v003a011/v003a011.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. That answers perfectly what I want to know.

Comment: Sorry, I will do that.