# What is the best known gap between ZPP and Deterministic communication complexity?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, communication-complexity, derandomization

I know that $N(f) \times coN(f) \geq D(f)$. This means that $ZPP(f) \geq \sqrt{D(f)}$. Is this separation tight?

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20901/6973 ​ ​